# UpdateView define primary key

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to set my primary key in a class based view to a unique value from my models.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict

class Stuff(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Thing", unique=True)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Item")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.thing

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item
```

**views.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView

class NewStuff(CreateView):
    model = Stuff
    form_class = NewStuffForm
    template_name = 'stuff.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('search_stuff')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'add':
                form = self.get_form()
                data = form.save()
            else:
                data['error'] = "No option has been selected"
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'New Stuff'
        context['stuff_url'] = reverse_lazy('search_stuff')
        context['action'] = 'add'
        return context


class EditStuff(UpdateView):
    model = Stuff
    form_class = NewStuffForm
    template_name = 'stuff.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('search_stuff')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'edit':
                form = self.get_form()
                data = form.save()
            else:
                data['error'] = '"No option has been selected"
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'New Stuff'
        context['stuff_url'] = reverse_lazy('search_stuff')
        context['action'] = 'edit'
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Stuff

class NewStuffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.visible_fields():
            form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = Stuff
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        data = {}
        form = super()
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                data['error'] = form.errors
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return data
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('stuff/add/', NewStuff.as_view(), name='new_stuff'),
    path('stuff/edit/<str:pk>', EditStuff.as_view(), name='edit_stuff'),
]
```

How can I set the **pk** on the view "EditStuff" equal to **thing** from the "Stuff" model?
I understand that I can get the primary key with self.kwargs['pk']. However, I do not know how to set it equal to the primary key...

My best guess is that I should do it inside the dispatch method, nevertheless, I am not entirely sure about it.

Comment: is there any reason why you cant set the `stuff` column as a primary key directly? It's done by adding [primary_key=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key) to the column definition

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I want to have the ability to edit freely the `thing` column. By setting it as the primary key it could lead to various problems, not now but maybe in the future. Django documentation suggests not to change primary keys. In contrast, I can change the values in the `thing` column without running into any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set **`slug_field`** and **`slug_url_kwarg`** attributes in your view as

```
class EditStuff(UpdateView):
    slug_field = "thing"
    slug_url_kwarg = "thing"
    # rest of your code
```

Then, update the URL as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('stuff/add/', NewStuff.as_view(), name='new_stuff'),
    path('stuff/edit/<str:thing>', EditStuff.as_view(), name='edit_stuff'),
]
```